# Possible to use a composite index to sort an update query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, indexing

We have an update query that needs to use the "order by" clause to ensure we update the correct row as follows:

```
UPDATE `plugin_name_codes`
USE|FORCE INDEX abc
SET `plugin_name_entry_id` = 2
WHERE `plugin_name_codes`.`plugin_name_form_id` = 3
AND (plugin_name_entry_id IS NULL) 
ORDER BY /*plugin_name_form_id asc, plugin_name_entry_id asc,*/ id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

We want to use an index to do the sorting for the ID column, but:

1. Index Hints are not used in UPDATE queries (according to the MySQL documentation).
2. The ORDER BY clause appears to ignore the index no matter how I create the indexes (i.e.
   using all three queried columns (plugin_name_entry_id, plugin_name_form_id, and id), or
   just the first 2 columns.
3. and the no matter which columns I include in the ORDER BY clause, the query always 
   ignores the index.

This ORDER clause adds a full 1 second to each query which is very unacceptable. Anyone know  how I can use the index to sort by ID, or some other workaround?

Comment: Any reason you don't use 2 queries in a transaction?

Comment: yup, the UPDATE FOR that we would need to use ends up blocking the database for a long time (for some reason) :-/

Comment: I meant a SELECT for the ID, then an UPDATE via the ID.

Comment: If I were to use a select, then I'd have to use "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE", which would temporarily block ...but I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: What if you do a "normal" SELECT, just to try out the sorting mess: What is the performance diff there?

Answer (score 0):

Just briefly on composite indexes; the first thing to consider is the way you will be querying your data. If you have a composite key such as `(col1, col2)` and you attempt to query `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col2 = 5`, the index will not be used because you need to `SELECT` all the keys from the left first.

With `UPDATE`, the only time an index will be used is with a `WHERE` clause (and possibly `ORDER BY`). Taking into consideration the information above, you will need to make sure that the left most column of your index is being used (`plugin_name_form_id`). If you had a composite key of `(col1, plugin_name_form_id)`, that update statement would not make any use of the index. You could also reverse the order of the index `(plugin_name_form_id, col1)` for it to be useful.

Hope this helps.